# Mod_rewrite not working on ISPConfig 3 Server

Tags: mod-rewrite, drupal

## Problem

I recently migrated a Drupal site from a shared hosting server to my own VM. Everything appears to work correctly, except clean urls.

**My VM Setup**

- Ubuntu 10.04
- LAMP
- ISPConfig 3

## What I've tried

From reading up on a number of drupal forums I've tried the following in this order

1. Check that mod_rewrite is installed and enabled
2. Changed PHP from FastCGI to Mod_PHP (prefer to use FastCGI or suPHP though to avoid having tmp/files folders with 777 permissions)
3. Changed the Redirect type to L in ISPConfig Sites->domain.com->Redirect
4. Changed /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/> 
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       ...
   </Directory>
   ```

Not sure about points 3 and 4, I do want *all* domains to be able to use mod_rewrite out of the box.

## Question

Have I done something wrong or am I missing a step? Ultimately I would like to use FastCGI and clean urls working on all ISPConfig 3 domains without having to make any changes to individual domain settings.

Any ideas appreciated, I'll try them all.

Comment: How is it not working? What are you expecting to happen, what happens instead, and what do the logs say?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2):

ISPConfig 3 Manual says:

> Fast-CGI:
>
> Advantages:
>
> - Scripts will be executed with user privileges of the web site;
> - More than one PHP version can be run as FastCGI;
> - Might be better in speed compared to CGI and suPHP.
>
> Disadvantages:
>
> - php.ini values cannot be changed via PHP scripts, vhost files, .htaccess files. But it is possible to use the *Custom php.ini
>     settings* field on the *Options* tab of a web site in ISPConfig to
>     specify custom php.ini settings (see chapter 4.6.1.1).

Instead .htaccess file use ISPConfig's Apache Directives:

Site -> Website -> Web Domain -> Options tab

Apache Directives:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Drupal 6 INSTALL.txt says:

> If the default Drupal theme is not displaying properly and links on the page
>      result in "Page Not Found" errors, try manually setting the $base_url variable
>      in the settings.php file if not already set. It's currently known that servers
>      running FastCGI can run into problems if the $base_url variable is left
>      commented out (see http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=19656).

Answer (score 0):

The redirect tab within ISPConfig is only for domain redirect and not for app specific one like Drupal'.

Did you check if .htaccess files are recognized as directives?

You should find a like for that in the global apache2 conf